# Python: Float Object is not Iterable

Tags: python

I wrote the code below to complete the assignment:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
total = 0
count = 0 
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    pos = line.find(':')
    num = float(line[pos+1:])
for number in num:
    total = total +num
    count += 1
print 'Average spam confidence:', total/count
```

The system keep coming out error message reading that

> float object is not iterable

I know that I made a mistake from `for number in num:`
And the correct answer is:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
total = 0
count = 0 
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    pos = line.find(':')
    num = float(line[pos+1:])
    total = total +num
    count += 1
print 'Average spam confidence:', total/count
```

but my question is :
in the correct answer, is float object also iterable?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: How should an iteration over 3.14 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Python [glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) notes, an object is an iterable if it is "capable of returning its members one at a time." `num` is a float, which is just just one number, and it cannot return it's elements one at a time like a list, a set, or a dictionary. Thus, it makes no sense to write `for number in num:` - for this to work, `num` should be a iterable, so that it can return it's members one at a time as `number`. Instead, you should just add the `num` to the `total` directly by calling `total = total + num` (or even better, `total += num`)

Comment: Note that you could do `for number in range(num)` which works for integer arguments